# location and size of jtextarea in jscrollpane is not set

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea, absolutelayout

I am working on the editor. I am using Java swing for it. I have embedded a `JTextArea` with `JScrollPane`. i want to position the `jtextarea` of particular size at the middle of `JScrollPane`. To do this I used `setLocation` function. But this is not working?

```
public class ScrollPaneTest extends JFrame {
private Container myCP;
private JTextArea resultsTA;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private  JPanel jpanel;

public ScrollPaneTest() {
resultsTA = new JTextArea(50,50);
resultsTA.setLocation(100,100);
jpanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
jpanel.add(resultsTA,BorderLayout.CENTER);

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jpanel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);

setSize(800, 800);
setLocation(0, 0);
myCP = this.getContentPane();
myCP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
myCP.add(scrollPane);
setVisible(true);
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
 });
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
     new ScrollPaneTest();
     }
}
```

Comment: See also [*How to Use Scroll Panes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and the [examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#eg) found there.

Comment: Use `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation` instead of using a `WindowListener`, just makes the code cleaner, IMHO

Answer (score 8):

You simply have to add the `JTextArea` to the `JScrollPane`, and add it to the `CENTER` of the `JPanel` having `BorderLayout`.

Don't use AbsolutePositioning. Add a proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html), and let LayoutManager do the rest for positioning and sizing your components on the screen.

In order to use the `setBounds(...)` method you have to use a `null` Layout for your component, which is not worth using, provided the perspective, as mentioned in the first paragraph of the [AbsolutePositioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html). Though in the code example provided by you, you are doing both the thingies together i.e. using Layout and using AbsolutePositioning, which is wrong in every way. My advice **STOP DOING IT** :-)

In the example provided the <kbd>ROWS</kbd> and <kbd>COLUMNS</kbd> provided by you are sufficient to size the `JTextArea` by the Layout concern.

Code Example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example
{
    private JTextArea tarea;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScrollPane Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        JScrollPane textScroller = new JScrollPane();
        tarea = new JTextArea(30, 30);
        textScroller.setViewportView(tarea);

        contentPane.add(textScroller);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Example().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```